# What am I doing wrong with this adding fractions problem: $\frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$?

Tags: fractions

> The problem is $$\frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$$

I found the LCD which is $6$. Then I multiplied $2\times 3=6$ and $2\times 2=4$. So the new problem is 
$$\frac{5}{6} + \frac{4}{6} = \frac{11}{6}$$
$\frac{11}{6}$ simplified is $1 \frac{5}{6}$ but that's not an answer I can select.

Comment: Because $5+4=9$

Comment: @KennyLau  I hate it when that happens!

Comment: @KennyLau you may as well make that an answer

Comment: Actually $5+4=11$.  The OP was using octal arithmetic.  However, in octal arithmetic $11/6$ simplifies to $1\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi as long as were making silly/snarky quips I'd respond to "but that's not an answer I can select" with "you could if you were really persistent".

Answer (score 1):

As Kenny Lau so thoughtfully pointed out, $5+4=9$.
$$\frac{5}{6}+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{5}{6}+\frac{4}{6}=\frac{9}{6}=\frac{3}{2}$$